# Cannot find module './fonoapi.node.js' but when listing, the module is shown

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use fonoapi-nodejs. I installed it using `npm install fonoapi-nodejs --save`.

Then when I try to acces it using `var fonoapi = require('./fonoapi.node.js');`

It gives me an error `Error: Cannot find module './fonoapi.node.js'` and when I list the npm packages using `npm list --depth=0` the package 
`├── body-parser@1.16.1
├── cookie-parser@1.4.3
├── debug@2.6.3
├── ejs@2.5.6
├── express@4.14.1
├── fonoapi-nodejs@0.1.1
├── morgan@1.7.0
└── serve-favicon@2.3.2` is listed there.

Answer (score 1):

Change `require('./fonoapi.node.js')` to `require('fonoapi-nodejs')` to load from `node_modules`.

When you do `npm list`, that is showing the contents of your `node_modules` directory. But you are including `./` at the start of the path, which tells `require()` to use a relative path rather than the `node_modules` directory.

Additionally, `npm list` shows that the module name is `fonoapi-nodejs` and not `fonoapi.node.js`.

(And yes, it appears that the documentation for `fonoapi-nodejs` shows the usage you have. In this situation, it's wrong, though.)